# How to Customize ListView Seletion in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to customize the selection effect of the items in the listView, but I don't know the way.

Will be useful if I should change the selection item background with a different png when the user select the item.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want icons in listview? Your question is not clear.

Comment: this sounds like a design question.

Comment: no I want a way to change the default select effect of the listview in android... (in android listview by default when you click an item this became something like blue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector for this:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:divider="@null" 
      android:dividerHeight="0dip"
      android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

the selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable" />
</selector>
```

Here is a [good tutorial](http://android-journey.blogspot.jp/2009/12/android-selectors.html) for it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is selector
Create a selector xml in res and set the background for the list item to the selector xml.
Example:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />
      <item 
       android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
    </selector>`

Also look at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList